# Looping Over a String Gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, string, replace, lowercase

I'm writing a function to make a string lowercase in C++. It works perfectly fine, but after the last character, it gives a segmentation fault. My code is below:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string lowercase(string str)
{
    string ans = str;
    for (int i=0; i < ans.size(); i++)
    {
        ans[i] = tolower(ans[i]);
        cout << ans[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    lowercase("TEST");
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try fulfilling your promise to return something from that function, or, change the return type to `void`. And crank up your warnings; this should have been caught.

Comment: Why not use `transform`?

Comment: you return "junk" and the destructor is called on that junk.

Comment: I'm not using transform because I haven't heard of it. I did a bit of googling, and everything told me I had to iterate over the string to transform individual characters.

Comment: Along with returning junk, you have another slight problem: if `ans` contains any "extended ASCII" characters (e.g., letters with accents) it'll usually look like a negative number. You normally want to cast to `unsigned char` before passing to `tolower` (or `toupper`, `isalpha`, etc.)

Comment: Or use `tolower(ans[I], locale());` from `<locale>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning on the warnings, you may spot the error yourself:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -Wall
```

**Errors:**

```
main.cpp: In function ‘std::string lowercase(std::string)’:
main.cpp:9:21: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int i=0; i < ans.size(); i++)
                     ^
main.cpp:14:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

Your function returns a string, but you have not specified a string to return.
You can fix the problem by returning your **ans** variable:

```
 string lowercase(string str)
{
    string ans = str;
    for (int i=0; i < ans.size(); i++)
    {
        ans[i] = tolower(ans[i]);
        cout << ans[i]<<endl;
    }
    return ans;
}
```